# Order columns by year independently in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

Data:

```
set.seed(0)
Temp <- data.frame(year=rep(1:3,each=4),V1=floor(rnorm(12)*2),V2=floor(rnorm(12)*2))

   year V1 V2
1     1  2 -3
2     1 -1 -1
3     1  2 -1
4     1  2 -1
5     2  0  0
6     2 -4 -2
7     2 -2  0
8     2 -1 -3
9     3 -1 -1
10    3  4  0
11    3  1  0
12    3 -2  1
```

I want to reorder V1 and V2 independently within each year. I can do it with 10 lines, but I believe there must be a more beautiful way to do it.

Desired output:

```
   year V1 V2
1     1 -1 -3
2     1  2 -1
3     1  2 -1
4     1  2 -1
5     2 -4 -3
6     2 -2 -2
7     2 -1  0
8     2  0  0
9     3 -2 -1
10    3 -1  0
11    3  1  0
12    3  4  1
```

Comment: For variety, a base R option is `Reduce(rbind, lapply(split(Temp, Temp$year), function(x) data.frame(lapply(x, sort))))`. This uses a nested loop (with `lapply`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do

```
library(dplyr)
Temp %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(V1=sort(V1), V2=sort(V2))
```

which returns

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   year [3]
    year    V1    V2
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    -1    -3
 2     1     2    -1
 3     1     2    -1
 4     1     2    -1
 5     2    -4    -3
 6     2    -2    -2
 7     2    -1     0
 8     2     0     0
 9     3    -2    -1
10     3    -1     0
11     3     1     0
12     3     4     1
```

And if you needed to do that with all columns, you could do

```
Temp %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate_all(sort)
```

Comment: So simple, nice.  I had to use `mutate_all(funs(sort(., na.last = T)))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Temp)[,c("V1","V2"):=list(sort(V1),sort(V2)),year]
```

Comment: @MrFlick thank you. just fixed now , it is just the same as your solution , wriiten within the data.table context

Answer (score 0):

If you use plyr and you know the column names, you can easily do this using ddply:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(Temp, "year", summarize, V1=sort(V1), V2=sort(V2))
   year V1 V2
1     1 -1 -3
2     1  2 -1
3     1  2 -1
4     1  2 -1
5     2 -4 -3
6     2 -2 -2
7     2 -1  0
8     2  0  0
9     3 -2 -1
10    3 -1  0
11    3  1  0
12    3  4  1
```

If you don't know the column names, you'd have to make a function to do it:

```
> ddply(Temp, "year", function(x) { as.data.frame(lapply(x, sort)) })
   year V1 V2
1     1 -1 -3
2     1  2 -1
3     1  2 -1
4     1  2 -1
5     2 -4 -3
6     2 -2 -2
7     2 -1  0
8     2  0  0
9     3 -2 -1
10    3 -1  0
11    3  1  0
12    3  4  1
```